# Call to undefined function mcrypt_get_block_size()

Tags: php, mcrypt

Call to undefined function `mcrypt_get_block_size()`

```
php version - 5.6.6
os- yosemite 10.10.2
mcrypt version- 2.5.8
```

Need help

Answer (score 1):

You may actually have to add a symlink in /etc/php5/apache/conf.d to the mcrypt.ini file. After that, restart the webserver and inspect phpinfo().

Comment: Might be helpful to add detail about "symlink".

Comment: My configuration may have changed in two years.
On my machine, apache has the mcrypt installed as module. I enabled this module using

 `sudo a2enmod mcrypt`

then in the folder mentioned there will be a link to mods-available/mcrypt.ini

Please note I'm using a linux flavor, not OSX.

Answer (score 0):

You have to enable the mcrypt extension.

Add the following line to the php.ini:

```
extension=mcrypt.so
```

Then restart your webserver.

Comment: Run phpinfo() and make sure the extension shows as loaded.

Answer (score 0):

For people who are on OSX

```
php -v
```

will give you the php version, and if you have `brew` do:

```
brew search mcrypt
```

you will see things like

```
homebrew/php/php53-mcrypt  homebrew/php/php55-mcrypt  homebrew/php/php70-mcrypt
homebrew/php/php54-mcrypt  homebrew/php/php56-mcrypt
```

install the one appropriate to your php version

then look at the /usr/local/etc/php/x.x/conf.d/ext-mcrypt.ini and add the contents to your php.ini.

restart your webserver and see the phpinfo().  you should see mcrypt loaded as a module.

Comment: i could not find  /usr/local/etc/php/x.x/conf.d/ext-mcrypt.ini  please explain more